# SharePoint Online modern pages - add section name and make it collapsible

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

I created a modern page in SharePoint Online.
Is there any way to add the section name and also to make it collapsible by code?

```
    const page = await sp.web.addClientsidePage(name, "Name");
    
    const commDisabled = page.commentsDisabled;
    page.commentsDisabled = true;
    const valueLayoutType = page.layoutType;
    page.layoutType = "NoImage";
    const htmlInfo "Hello!"
    const section1 = page.addSection();
    section1.addColumn(12);
    section1.addControl(new ClientsideText(htmlInfo ));

    await page.save();
```

Comment: You can do it with webpart. SPO restricts any scripts on page. In the SharePoint Online, you cannot put scripts on the page in the same way as you can in the classic SharePoint one due to security restrictions. Maybe on https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ you can find more detailed answer to your question

Comment: @Maxim probably it's about new "collapsible sections" on modern pages, see below

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK pnpjs does not support [collapsible sections](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/07/01/sharepoint-collapsible-sections-on-modern-pages/) (yet?). So, the answer is - no, there is no API released to make a collapsible section by code. Theoretically, you could try extending the pnpjs library yourself to support the collapsible sections (it seems that the parameters required are available in the `/sitepages` REST API). Or you can wait until Microsoft implements this support in pnpjs or in the new graph pages api.